# How to check if table td have at least one value?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function hasAtLeastOneValue(collection) {
  for (let x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
    if (collection[x].innerHTML.trim() !== "") {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false
}


var t3 = document.querySelectorAll('#lot_desc td');
console.log("Table has at least one value: ", hasAtLeastOneValue(t3))
```

```html
<table class="table tablecert1 table-bordered" id="lot_desc"> 
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">BAGS</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">No</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Weight</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Mark</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <th style="text-align: center;">Gross</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Net</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_1" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_1" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_1" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_1" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_2" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_2" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_2" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_2" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_3" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_3" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_3" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_3" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_4" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_4" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_4" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_4"class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_5" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_5" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_5" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_5" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_6" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_6" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_6" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_6" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a table contains 6 rows and 4 columns.
So when we click Save button I want to check this table has at least one datum entered

If any one td is entered means return true (allow to save the data this time). If table is completely blank or (not entered anything) means return false (not allow to save to database)

```
var x = document.getElementById("lot_desc").rows.length;

if(x == 0){
  alert("not empty")
  return true;
}else{
  alert("Table is empty")
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Clicking a save button infers that a user is involved entering (or not entering) data. How does said user actually enter data into a `<td>`? Explain the layout of `<table>` in HTML.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML on which this code runs to produce a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to help.

Comment: Your code is almost perfect. You just thought wrong that you need to check the HTML of td rather than input's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `innerHTML` and make sure to apply `trim()`

```js
function hasAtLeastOneValue() {
  let hasValue = false
  const collection = document.querySelectorAll('#lot_desc td');
  for (let x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
    if (collection[x].querySelector('input').value.trim() !== "") {
      hasValue = true;
    }
  }
  console.log('has at least one value', hasValue)
  return hasValue
}
```

```css
table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="table tablecert1 table-bordered" id="lot_desc">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">BAGS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">No</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Weight</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Mark</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Gross</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Net</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_1" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_1" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_1" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_1" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_2" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_2" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_2" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_2" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_3" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_3" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_3" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_3" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_4" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_4" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_4" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_4" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_5" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_5" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_5" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_5" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_6" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="gross_6" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="net_6" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
    <td><input style="" id="mark_6" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<button onclick="hasAtLeastOneValue()" )>Test for values</button>
<div style='height:100px'></div>
```

Comment: Revised answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: am looking for atleast that table shouldnt be blank when click the save button and prevent the save data..In that table have 6 rows and 4 columns.In these any cell is entered is allow to save to database.

Comment: @ashnima Please edit your question to show exactly what you are talking about, or be less exacting about the answers you receive. You provide no example table in your question, and yet you have nothing but criticism for the answers you've received because they don't match the requirements which you have not shared with us.

Comment: Almost right this answer but i have one table only..In this one table i have to check these senarios

Comment: That example will work on any table - look at how I reuse the function

Comment: @Kinglish but when am using this function.If table is empty it showing true. and if it has value also its showing true. Please check i have added snippet

Comment: @Kinglish can u see my table i have added it

Comment: @ashnima - give that a try. revised answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const isEmpty = x => ![...x.querySelectorAll("td")] // get all td elements from x
                      .some(e => e.innerHTML)       // check if any td is not empty

console.log(isEmpty(document.querySelector("#empty-table")))
console.log(isEmpty(document.querySelector("#empty-table-2")))
console.log(isEmpty(document.querySelector("#not-empty-table")))
```

```html
<table id="empty-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="empty-table-2">
</table>

<table id="not-empty-table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need.to check the `value` of your `input` elements:

```js
function hasAtLeastOneValue(collection) {
  for (let s,x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
    if ((s=collection[x].value.trim()) !== "") { console.log(x,s);
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false
}


var t3 = document.querySelectorAll('#lot_desc input');

// Or, as a one-liner:

const res=[...document.querySelectorAll('#lot_desc input')].some(inp=>inp.value.trim()>"");


console.log("Table has at least one value: ", hasAtLeastOneValue(t3),res);
```

```html
<table class="table tablecert1 table-bordered" id="lot_desc"> 
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">BAGS</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">No</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Weight</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Mark</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
    <th style="text-align: center;">Gross</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;">Net</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_1" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_1" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_1" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_1" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_2" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_2" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_2" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_2" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_3" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_3" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_3" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_3" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_4" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_4" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_4" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_4"class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_5" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_5" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_5" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_5" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input style="" id="no_6" class="form-control no" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="gross_6" class="form-control gross" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="net_6" class="form-control net" type="text"></td>
     <td><input style="" id="mark_6" class="form-control mark" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```